# Orgchart running outside component - Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a project in Angular8. I built a component to use the dabeng´s orgchart
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wOQT.png): https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart (not the angular component, the original project).
It´s pretty simple and has a just .js file called jquery.orgchart.js and it does contains another script in the .html (see the code below):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  var datasource = {
  'name': 'Lao Lao',
  'title': 'general manager',
  'children': [
    { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
    { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
        { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Dan Dan', 'title': 'engineer' }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'senior engineer' }
      ]
    },
    { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' }
  ]
};

var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
  'data' : datasource,
  'pan': true,
  'zoom': true,
  'direction': 'l2r',
  'nodeContent': 'title',
  'nodeTemplate': nodeTemplate,
  'draggable': true
});


$('#btn-export-hier').on('click', function() {
  if (!$('pre').length) {
    var hierarchy = oc.getHierarchy();
    $('#btn-export-hier').after('<pre>').next().append(JSON.stringify(hierarchy, null, 2));
  }
});
});
</script>
```

Problem is that I need to change this var datasource value (and use my db data). Since I can´t use script tags in .html Angular file I pasted the script above in another external .js file (jquery.orgchartdata.js) and built this "solution" to run the script in Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prod-char-edit',
  templateUrl: './prod-char-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prod-char-edit.component.css'],
})

export class ProdCharEditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    const script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script.src ="../../assets/js/orgchart/jquery.orgchart.js";
    script2.src ="../../assets/js/orgchart/jquery.orgchartdata.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

};
```

Right now I can run the script properly...
[Project picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wOQT.png)
but I can´t change the datasource value (Adding a Service i.e.) because I can´t pass the new datasource value from Component to external .js file (jquery.orgchartdata.js) or make the external .js file access any function in Component.

I´ve tried to create a function in Component and paste the script there, but 2 problems came up:
1 - I can´t integrate both scripts. I can´t make the jquery.orgchart.js access the second script content.
2 - This line (var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart) just doesn´t work when it´s inside the Component. It keeps saying "Property 'orgchart' does not exist on type 'JQuery'".

Comment: why you don't want to use the angular version?
https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart

Comment: Because it is 13 months without maintenance and doesn´t have a features that are important to me.

Comment: you can use ES6 version but if you insist to use Jquery version follow steps was described here: https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope
this resolves  "Property 'orgchart' does not exist on type 'JQuery'" eror

Comment: I really would like to use ES6 version, nut I´m too stupid to run it. Thank you very much for your help. I´m fighting here for 4 days now on this issue.